# Error with a references C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, loops, time, reference

I try to calculate how many operations through the loop made for 1 sec.
For this I remember time when I start to calculate loop and check time at every iteration.
My idea - when numbers of seconds are differ for this two timemoments I printf how many loop iteration were made.

Here is my code:

```
#include <ctime>
int main()
{
    // For timing
     time_t t, tstep;
     struct tm* now, *step;

    // this time will change at every iteration
    t = time(0);
    now = localtime(&t);

    // save time of the start moment
    tstep = t;
    step = localtime(&tstep);

    // counter of loop cycles
    int count = 0; 

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1e100 ; i++)
    {
        // ... here is some calculations    
        t = time(0);
        now = localtime(&t);
        count++;

        if (now->tm_sec != step->tm_sec)
        {
            tstep = time(0);
            step = localtime(&tstep);
             //printf("number of lines %i \n", count );
             count = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What is the problem: every time I refresh `now` `step` became the same value! While `t` and `tstep` are the different!

Looks like this is because of references: maybe when I use `tstep = t` this mean that addresses of this variables refers to `t` both. So changing `t` changes `now` and `tstep`.

How to solve this problem? How to copy just value of `t` to `step`? Or there is another actual way?

Comment: If you downvote, can you just explain why?

Comment: "_Looks like this is because of references_" You are **not** using references anywhere in the code presented.

Comment: Also, this is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: _every time I refresh `now` `step` became the same value_ No wonder if you assign them directly after each other with just a few microseconds (maybe even nanoseconds) in between...

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius OK, it is just "address of" not reference. Can you clarify my mistake for me?

Comment: @kim366 I put my code and told what's wrong/ You can use it just copy+paste and you can read whats wrong. So why is is not MCVE??

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam Identify the wrong lines and make a short separate example so it's easier to analyze it, rather than having 100 lines of code..

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam Because you [**can't** copy-paste it](http://ideone.com/n878kN)..

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I made it MCVE

Comment: @kim366 Ok, is it good now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`localtime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime) function is not thread-safe and more importantly not reentrant.

The pointer it return is most likely a pointer to an internal `static` buffer. This means that each `localtime` call returns the very same pointer to the very same "buffer" (structure). In fact, if you read the linked reference, the buffer (structure) can be shared between multiple functions.

This can easily be checked by using a debugger and compare the pointers returned by the function.

If you need different values, then you need to copy the data instead of copy the pointer. This is simply done by making `now` and `step` structure *instances* instead of pointers. Then dereference the pointer returned by `localtime`:

```
struct tm now, step;  // Note: Not pointers!

...

now = *localtime(&t);  // Dereference returned pointer
```

Comment: Thank you for your sympathy! I was unpleasantly surprised at the amount of negativity that was poured out on me by downvotes and commentary, it's nice that someone thinks about how to help, and not how to crap :)